# Pass an array of user defined type to PostgreSQL 15 Stored Procedure (NpgsqlC)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I have a User Defined Type **key_value_int_int** in PostgreSQL 15

`CREATE TYPE key_value_int_int AS ("key" int, "value" int);`

and Stored Procedure **sp_update_table** with parameter of type **array of key_value_int_int**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_update_table(p_id integer, p_dictionary key_value_int_int[])
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
    DECLARE item key_value_int_int;
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = p_id;

    -- BEGIN
    FOREACH item IN ARRAY p_dictionary LOOP
        INSERT INTO table_name(id, [key], [value])
        VALUES (p_id, item.key, item.value);
    END LOOP;
    -- END

    COMMIT;
END;
$$;
```

How to pass an array of user defined type objects to the procedure using .NET NpgSql?

```
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
await using var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
try
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();

    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    throw AsDatabaseException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the answer while writing the question:

```
var query = "CALL public.sp_update_table(3, array[row(1,1),row(2,2)]::key_value_int_int[])";
```

where **public.sp_update_table()** is:

```
public.sp_update_table(p_id integer, p_dictionary key_value_int_int[])
```